# IMPORTHTML - Add a Column with the URL

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importhtml

I'm currently using `IMPORTHTML` to import tables from a website with 5 columns.

I need to add a 6th column that is called "url", which will be the URL that I used in the `IMPORTHTML` formula.

How can I do so in an automated way? Ideally the formula itself should return it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to put the URL in the sixth column and refer to that column in your `importhtml()` formulas, rather than doing this the other way around. Those formulas would then look like this:

`=importhtml(F2, "table", 1)`

To answer your question, you can extract URLs from existing `importhtml()` formulas like this:

`=regexextract( formulatext(A2), """(.+?)""" )`